# ¿Cómo explicar este comportamiento del CASE?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hay un comportamiento del `CASE` que siempre me ha producido una cierta duda. Normalmente si veo este código:

```
case when id = 1 then 1 else '' end
```

Suelo modificarlo por algo así:

```
case when id = 1 then 1 else 0 end
```

o bien

```
case when id = 1 then 1 else NULL end
```

Es decir, estoy generando una columna que apriori, tendría un valor numérico, por lo que no parece consistente en el `ELSE` retornar una cadena, aun siendo un "blanco", por lo que me parece más consistente retornar un valor numérico o en todo caso un `NULL`.

Sin embargo, este código es absolutamente funcional, y el blanco que se retorna es de alguna forma es coercionado a un 0.

```
select id,
    case when id = 1 then 1 else '' end,
    case when id = 2 then 1 else '' end
    from (select 1 as id union 
          select 2
          ) T

+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
+---+---+---+
| 2 | 0 | 1 |
+---+---+---+
```

Sin embargo si en vez de una cadena en blanco `''` retornamos otra cadena:

```
select id,
    case when id = 1 then 1 else 'no' end,
    case when id = 2 then 1 else 'no' end
    from (select 1 as id union 
          select 2
          ) T

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 73
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'no' to data type int.
```

¿A que se debe este comportamiento? ¿Esto está documentado en algún lugar?

Comment: Este comportamiento también ocurre en Oracle?

Comment: @Jesús, en Oracle una clausula similar daría error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según la documentación del [`CASE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> **Return Types**
>
> Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in
>   result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression. For more
>   information, see [Data Type Precedence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (Transact-SQL).

Es decir, se retorna, el tipo de dato de mayor precedencia (consultar enlace) de cualquiera de los valores retornados mediante el `when` o el `else` . En este ejemplo, el valor más alto sería un entero, por consiguiente la cadena que retorna el `else` se convierten implícitamente a un entero. Y las cadenas en blanco ( `''`) al menos en `sql-server` se convierten al valor numérico `0`, algo que puede ser discutible y sin duda materia para otra pregunta-.

```
select convert(int, '')


-----------
0
```

Este es un comportamiento muy particular de `sql-server`, en otros motores los resultados son otros:

- **Oracle 11gR2**: `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR`
- **Postgres 9.4 a 12**: `Query Error: error: invalid input syntax for integer: ""`
- **Mysql 5.8 a 8**: Se hace una conversión implícita pero al tipo de dato de menor precedencia, es decir se transforma todo a una cadena.